How does one launch in multipass an end-of-life Ubuntu images into VM?
Short summary question: How can a developer get multipass VM access to previously available Ubuntu images that they were using, after End-of-Life?

Yes I know bionic is end-of-life. Here's the problem:
Our production server--which is currently running bionic--needs to be migrated to jammy. We need a side-by-side VM instance of it on its current bionic, for side-by-side testing migration issues, and possible debugging of current live production server during the migration period.
One day, after destroying the bionic VM instances to spin them back up, we got an unexpected error message:
launch failed: 'bionic' is not a supported alias. Please use `multipass find` for supported image aliases.

They withdrew access to bionic due to end-of-life. We had believed we could purchase extended support for it if we couldn't get the migration done in time. Apparently you can for your production server but not for running multipass VM's on macOS or Windows.
Now we are left in a position where we can't migrate because we can't side-by-side test the new jammy vs. the old bionic, in order to see assess how package versions are behaving differently. And figure out migration adjustments to the codebase and other scripts.
We can no longer debug issues on the live production server because we can't even spin up a VM of bionic anymore!
What can we do to rescue our situation and get our ability to launch multipass instances of bionic back, so we can finish our tardy migration to jammy? Ideally there is some way to patch in a url or reference-symbol to the old bionic, and not be forced to pick from the current available aliases.
Thanks a bunch, in advance!

Since this question is related to upgrading to a supported release, it is not off topic as per https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Extended support was available for some architectures only. so 18.04 is End of Life or in Extended Support (ESM) depending on details you didn't provide (ie. architecture)

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Architecture of production server is x86_64 Intel Xeon. Architecture of developer workstations running multipass VM is arm64 but if we can be rescued to do the upgrade by borrwing an x86_64 PC please advise.
